# How to deal with arrays in PHP language

Tags: php, html

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if(!$con)
{
    die("not ok");
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"uoh");  


$q1 = "SELECT * FROM student_record INNER JOIN degree_plan ON
 student_record.course_number = degree_plan.course_number 
 INNER JOIN courses ON student_record.course_number = 
 courses.course_number where student_record.id  = 201102887 AND degree_plan.major='COE'";

$result = mysqli_query($con , $q1 ) ;
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $data[$row["term_no"]][] =  array(
        'code' => $row["code"],
        'grade' => $row["grade"]
    );

}


echo '<table width="200" border="1">';
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<th>courses</th>";
   echo "<th>terms</th>";
   echo "<th>grades</th>";
   echo "</tr>";

foreach($data as $term=>$otherrow) {
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($otherrow as $data) {
        if($count == 0) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $data["code"]. "</td>";
            echo '<td rowspan="'.count($otherrow).'">' . $term. '</td>';
            echo "<td>" . $data["grade"]. "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            }

        else 

        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $data["code"]. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $data["grade"]. "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        $count++;
    }
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

I have this code and it work very well but I faced problem when I want to add more column .
I tried to add fourth column(`echo "<td>" . $row["crd"]. "</td>";` ) but there is no result .It give me empty cells. how I can do that?

I want add add this echo `"<td>" . $row["crd"]. "</td>";` column to my code.

Comment: Your variable is called `$data`, not `$row`. You're creating an array called `$data` inside your first loop, and then iterating though it later on. You're also re-using `$data` inside the inner foreach, which is going to over-write the contents. You should re-name one of those variables.

Comment: English is not my native language either, but you should really take the effort to understand it is `arrays` not `arraies`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there are two errors that have been noticed.

1. You are re-declaring `$data` in your second foreach loop
2. You don't have `$row` initiated anywhere, and atempting to echo `$row["crd"]` will result in an empty cell.

**Proposed Solution:**

Change the name of the `$data` value in the foreach loop to `$row` and hence solve both problems at the same time:

```
foreach($data as $term=>$otherrow) {
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($otherrow as $row) {
        if($count == 0) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["code"]. "</td>";
            echo '<td rowspan="'.count($otherrow).'">' . $term. '</td>';
            echo "<td>" . $row["grade"]. "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            }

        else 

        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["code"]. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["grade"]. "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        $count++;
    }
}
```

And when you add `echo "<td>" . $row["crd"]. "</td>";` now it should echo the value stored in the `$row` array (as long as the value was extracted from the table in the database in the first place of course).

Let me know if this worked for you.